# Trying to build project throws: requires callback functions but got a [object Promise]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes

I'm trying to access a function that I'm later going to use for changing some database values. However whenever I try to build the project I get:

> Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Promise]

My initial function is:

```
import fetch from '../../../../core/fetch';
import history from '../../../../core/history';


export const BOXOFFICE_CHECKING_IN = 'BOXOFFICE_CHECKING_IN';
export const BOXOFFICE_CHECKED_IN = 'BOXOFFICE_CHECKED_IN';
export const BOXOFFICE_CHECKED_IN_ERROR = 'BOXOFFICE_CHECKED_IN_ERROR';

export default function checkIn() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: BOXOFFICE_CHECKING_IN });

      const state = getState();
      const {
        order: {
          id: orderId,
        },
      } = state;

      const response = await fetch(
        `/api/event/orders/${orderId}/checkIn`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            order: orderId,
            checkedIn: true,
          }),
        }
      );

      if (response.status === 200) {
        dispatch({ type: BOOKING_CHECKED_IN });
      } else {
        const errorResponse = await response.json();
        if (errorResponse.code === 'card_error') {
          dispatch({ type: BOXOFFICE_CHECKED_IN_ERROR });
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  };
}
```

Which then feeds to the api:

```
import checkIn from '../handlers/api/orders/checkInCustomer';


...

export default (resources) => {
  const router = new Router();

...

  router.post('/orders/:orderId/checkIn', checkIn(resources));
```

Which then reaches the final function I wish to use:

```
export default async function checkIn(req, res) {

console.log('this is working fully');
    return true;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you want to be passing the function `checkIn`, but when you call it using `checkIn(resources)` you're actually passing the return value (A promise that resolves to `true`).

You should be using:

```
router.post('/orders/:orderId/checkIn', checkIn);
```

Now, I'm assuming you want to do this because you want to pass resources into the `router.post` function, correct? What happens to the `request` and `response` objects?

```
                                 Where does resources go?
                                      v
export default async function checkIn(req, res) {
    console.log('this is working fully');
    return true;
}
```

You have a few ways of accomplishing what you're looking for.

1. Create a resources file, and import it. This is the ideal solution:

   ```
   const db = mysql.connect(...);
   const lang = lang.init();

   console.log('This file is only called once!');

   export default {
       db,
       lang,
   };
   ```

   And then in your code (/routes/checkIn.js):

   ```
   import { db } from '../resources';

   export default async function checkIn(req, res) {
       //Access db here
       //db.query...
   }
   ```
2. Wrap your code in an intermediate function:

   ```
   router.post('/orders/:orderId/checkIn', (req, res) => checkIn(req, res, resources));
   ```
3. [`Bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) resources to your checkIn function:

   ```
   const db = mysql.connect(...);
   const lang = lang.init();
   const resources = {db, lang};

   router.post('/orders/:orderId/checkIn', checkIn.bind(resources));
   ```

   And then in your code (/routes/checkIn.js):

   ```
   export default async function checkIn(req, res) {
       //Access this.db here
       //this.db.query...
   }
   ```

Comment: I see, many thanks for the response! Nearly all of the other requests pass the param `resources`, I assumed this contained the json data that was attached to the fetch call?

Comment: I'm working on a more detailed write-up, which explains the resources issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for that brilliant answer!